# Mozilla Firefox 75 - remove "Visit" in address bar

Tags: firefox, address-bar

I've tried everything, custom `userChrome.css` does not remove this line, anything other possible?

Please I need solution not link to "introduction into creating your own userChrome.css" in 20 pages.

[image]

Make the line highlighted in blue disappear.
Maybe just remove every 1st line in address bar?

This is current userChrome.css in case anyone can add the feature there.

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */

/* based on https://old.reddit.com/comments/fwhlva//fmolndz */
#urlbar[breakout][breakout-extend]:not([open]) {
top: calc((var(--urlbar-toolbar-height) - var(--urlbar-height)) / 2) !important;
left: 0 !important;
width: 100% !important;
}
#urlbar[breakout][breakout-extend]:not([open]) > #urlbar-input-container {
height: var(--urlbar-height) !important;
padding-block: 0px !important;
padding-inline: 0px !important;
}
#urlbar[breakout][breakout-extend][breakout-extend-animate] > #urlbar-background {
animation-name: none !important;
}
#urlbar[breakout][breakout-extend]:not([open]) > #urlbar-background {
box-shadow: none !important;
}

/* Status-bar */
#browser-bottombox { height: 20px; border-top: solid 0px #505050; }
.browserContainer>statuspanel { left: 4px !important; bottom: 0px; transition-duration: 0s !important; transition-delay: 0s !important; }
.browserContainer>statuspanel>.statuspanel-inner>.statuspanel-label { margin-left: 0px !important; border: none !important; padding: 0px !important; }

window[inFullscreen="true"] #browser-bottombox { display:none !important; }
window[inFullscreen="true"] .browserContainer>statuspanel[type="overLink"] .statuspanel-label { display:none !important; }

#statuspanel #statuspanel-label {
-moz-appearance: none !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
border: 0px solid black !important;
}

#statuspanel {
background-color: transparent !important;
border: none !important;
bottom: 18px !important; /* adjust*/
height: 18px !important; /* adjust */
max-width: 30% !important; /* Change the value to suite your needs */
transition: none !important;
}
/* 
  Firefox 57-70 users: https://www.jeffersonscher.com/gm/url-bar-tweaks.html
  You can copy/paste into a userChrome.css file, see https://www.userchrome.org/
*/
/* Remove " - Visit" or " - Search with" bar in the drop-down */
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult richlistitem:first-of-type[type*="heuristic"],
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult richlistitem:first-of-type[actiontype="searchengine"],
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult richlistitem:first-of-type[actiontype="visiturl"],
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult richlistitem:first-of-type[actiontype="keyword"],
  #urlbar-results #urlbarView-row-0,
  #urlbar-results .urlbarView-row:first-of-type {
    display:none !important;
  }
/* Hide line for searching sld.tld below "Visit" Line */
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult richlistitem:first-of-type[actiontype="visiturl"] +
  richlistitem[actiontype="searchengine"] {
    display:none !important;
  }
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult .autocomplete-richlistbox,
  #urlbarView-results, #urlbar-results {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  }

/* Restore persistent display of drop-marker */
  #urlbar:not(:hover) > .urlbar-textbox-container > .urlbar-history-dropmarker,
  .urlbar-history-dropmarker {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
/* Set max-height for items visible without scrolling */
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult .autocomplete-richlistbox,
  #urlbarView-results, #urlbar-results {
    height: unset !important;
    max-height: calc(30.5px * 10) !important;
  }
  /* Constrain drop-down width */
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult,
  #urlbar-results {
    max-width: 1200px !important;
    /* Removed for Firefox 70:
      margin-left: -22px !important; */
  }
  .urlbarView-row-inner {
    max-width:1185px !important;
  }
  .urlbarView-type-icon {
    margin-left: 4px !important;  
  }
  /* Remove excess width of one-off search engine buttons */
  #urlbar-results .searchbar-engine-one-off-item.dummy:not(.last-of-row) {
    display: none !important;
  }
  /* Firefox 70 */
  .urlbarView:not(.megabar){
    left: unset !important;
    right: unset !important;
  }
/* Default font sizes */
  .autocomplete-richlistitem[selected=true],
  .urlbarView-row[selected] {
    background-color: Highlight !important;
  }
  .autocomplete-richlistitem[selected=true] .ac-title, 
  .ac-title[selected],
  .autocomplete-richlistitem[selected=true] .ac-url, 
  .ac-url[selected],
  .autocomplete-richlistitem[selected=true] .ac-action,
  .ac-action[selected],
  .autocomplete-richlistitem[selected=true] .ac-separator,
  .ac-separator[selected],
  .urlbarView-row[selected] .urlbarView-title,
  .urlbarView-row[selected] .urlbarView-secondary,
  .urlbarView-row[selected] .urlbarView-title-separator {
    color: HighlightText !important;
  }
  /* Use default text matching style */
/* Prevent excess indenting of icons in Photon */
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult .autocomplete-richlistitem [anonid="type-icon-spacer"],
  #urlbar-results .autocomplete-richlistitem [anonid="type-icon-spacer"] {
    display: none !important;
  }
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult,
  #urlbar-results {
     --item-padding-start: 0 !important;
     --item-padding-end: 0 !important;
  }
/* Ability to scroll in Fx57 */
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult .autocomplete-richlistbox > scrollbox,
  #urlbarView-results, #urlbar-results {
    overflow-y: auto !important; 
    padding-right: 3px !important;
  }
  #PopupAutoCompleteRichResult .autocomplete-richlistbox {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
```

Comment: When you start by saying you've tried everything we know you haven't. Please list everything that you have tried, and then we'll suggest things that you haven't tried yet.